# Possible to assign custom post type to a user

Tags: php, wordpress

I am displaying a custom post type as tiles and am wondering if you can assign the IDs of these to a user? I am looking to provide a save for later function where I can then grab associated custom posts in the user profile area.

Would this be done by adding an array of custom post IDs to the user?

If so how would you go about adding them and removing? I was intending on having a save and unsave link within the post tile.

Thanks.

Comment: Posts are already assigned a user: `post_author`, provided you have given your Custom Post Type [support for 'author'](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#supports).

Comment: @George I know, but the idea is to be able to save a post to a user, so I can basically do a wishlist type of setup. Save/Remove this post for example.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is Off-Topic, as it's not to do with broken code, but I've answered anyway.

You'll probably want to use the [update_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) function to set a serialized array of posts next to each user, that fires on a [WP_AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) button to trigger the function that does the saving.

Each button would to pass either "add" or "remove" type arguments that the function could then use either to determine what to do.